# automatically show up pushed content angular

Tags: angularjs

I am adding new data to array, but it does not show up instantly, when i add a new data the table of info disappears and after refreshing, it shows all the data. Why my data isn't showing right a way in my table, how can i push data so it automatically shows up?

my AddInventory function

```
$scope.addInventory = function(inventory) {
    $http.post("http://localhost/api/v1/inventory/", inventory)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.info = data;
      });
};
```

input form for adding new data

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inventory.name" />
<input type="text" ng-model="inventory.description" />
<select ng-model="inventory.category" ng-options="category.name for category in category.objects">
     <option value="" selected>--Please select your category--</option> 
</select>
<!--<input type="text" ng-model="inventory.category.name" />-->
<input type="button" ng-click="addInventory(inventory)" value="Save" />
```

And here i am showing up my data

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
    <th>Nosaukums</th>
    <th>Apraksts</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="inventory in info.objects">  
    <td>{{inventory.name}}</td>
    <td>{{inventory.description}}</td>
    <td>{{inventory.category.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It looks like you are replacing $scope.info with your return data in the callback. If the ng-repeat does not find info.objects, it will not render anything. In any case you should probably push the new data to the array, not replace it with.

Comment: @Narretz any example? When i use push it shows in console push object doesnt have method push

Comment: If you are using objects, then you must specify a key in your object collection. info.objects.key = data. However, it's better to use arrays for ng-repeat.

Comment: @Narretz i changed `$scope.info.objects.key = data;` not it shows data when adding a new information, but that new info is showing just after refresh, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please change info.objects into info